# MaterialPageRoute is not working inside inkwell in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, velocity

I am trying to navigate to another page when user click an item...i have used InkWell widget and have used push() for passing argument..
I am not able to figure out whether the problem is in MaterialPAgeRoute or in Inkwell ontap() ...I had tried GestureDetector and also wrapped IgnorePointer inside the Inkwell's child... but it doesnt work

```
  import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/pages/home_detail_page.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';
import '../../models/catalog.dart';
import '../../widgets/themes.dart';
import 'catalog_image.dart';

//cataloglist-----
class CatalogList extends StatelessWidget {
  const CatalogList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: CatalogModel.items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final catalog = CatalogModel.items[index];
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomeDetailPage(
                catalog: catalog,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // onTap: () => {print("tapped on container")},
          child: CatalogItem(catalog: catalog),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

//catalog item------------
class CatalogItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Item catalog;

  const CatalogItem({Key? key, required this.catalog})
      : assert(catalog != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VxBox(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CatalogImage(
            image: catalog.image,
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              catalog.name.text.lg.color(MyTheme.darkBluishColor).bold.make(),
              catalog.desc.text.textStyle(context.captionStyle).make(),
              10.heightBox,
              //--space
              ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: [
                  "\$${catalog.price}".text.bold.xl.make(),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all(MyTheme.darkBluishColor),
                        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(StadiumBorder())),
                    child: "Buy".text.make(),
                  )
                ],
              ).pOnly(right: 8.0)
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
    ).white.rounded.square(150).make().py16();
  }
}
```

this is the page where I want to navigate

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/models/catalog.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';

class HomeDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Item catalog;
  const HomeDetailPage({Key? key, required this.catalog})
      : assert(catalog != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [Image.network(catalog.image)]),
    );
  }
}
```

this is a separate route page...

```
class MyRoutes {
  static String homeDetailsRoute = "/detail";
}
```

Comment: could you add error which is thrown?

Comment: there is no error showing.....onpressing the item.. i m not able to navigate to other page @Ruchit

Comment: is the catalog not null

Comment: yes..... @Kthree

Comment: I am not able to figure out whether the problem is in MaterialPAgeRoute or in Inkwell ontap() ...

Comment: is the onTap firing can you can log inside it to see if its firing

Comment: nope...... it is not working @Kthree

Comment: Try using a `GestureDetector` and see if that works, I'm not sure why your InkWell is not firing, please add more code from the file which contains the InkWell so we can troubleshoot better.

Comment: I had tried GestureDetector but it doesnt work @Advait

Comment: problem solved... there was problem with the homepage .... I forgot to remove CatalogList class from home page.....